# Concept Check -- Key Determination from Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, key, functional-dependencies

This is more of a concept check than anything, but suppose I have a relation R on attributes ABCD with the functional dependencies B -> ACD and C -> D. The solitary key for this relation is B, and a superkey for this relation is BC, correct?

Comment: It does not make sense to say "with the FDs B -> ACD and C -> D". You can't mean that those are the only ones, because if those are present so is B->A & others. Maybe you mean, those plus the ones they imply, and no others; but you didn't say that. Maybe you mean, only those and you are using a form for listing FDs where all determined attributes of a given determinant are named in one FD. But you didn't say that either. Maybe you mean, this is a minimal cover (in which case you must be using the preceding form). But you didn't say that either. So do you get that part of the concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only candidate key in your example is indeed `B`. Any collection of attributes containing `B` will be a superkey, e.g., `B` itself, `AB`, `BC` or `ABD`.

Answer (score -1):

candidate key is B.

As all the attributes can be derived from B, B becomes superkey..